# Updating System.Data.DataTable with Data from Excel File

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

I have a powershell script that is pulling data from a SQL database and populating data table, then writing the contents to csv file. The script is as below:

```
$dataSource = "DESKTOP-9CRH1HF\SQLEXPRESS"
$user = "sa"
$pwd = "Not4U2c@Al!"
$database = "Xperdyte"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;"

$query = "SELECT * from dbo.v_SpecProd_Export"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)
$table | Export-Csv -path c:\temp\temp.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
Get-Content c:\temp\temp.csv | select -Skip 1  | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Set-Content c:\temp\Xperdyte.csv
move-item "c:\temp\Xperdyte.csv" ("c:\1_PRODUCTION\ARMOR\Bom\DocProd_Africa_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.csv" -f (get-date))
$connection.Close()
```

The output in the CSV file is below:

```
1008891;20.000000;Roll;20;;TSB876ZA;06;;L15832ZA;Clear Leader Roll 300mm x 400m 22mic;4.060000;M   ;1;;S80795XL;0
1008891;20.000000;Roll;20;;TSB876ZA;06;;L17440ZA;Transparent leader Rolls 48mm x 600m;4.060000;M   ;1;;S80795XL;0
1008891;20.000000;Roll;20;;TSB876ZA;06;;S80795XL;Jumbo APR6 Black 1010 mm;1608.400000;M   ;1;;S80795XL;0
1008891;20.000000;Roll;20;;TSB876ZA;06;;TAD118ML;Adhesive Tape 24mm X 50m;4.060000;M   ;1;;S80795XL;0
1008891;20.000000;Roll;20;;TSB876ZA;06;;TAD123ML;Adhesive Transparent 24mm X 350m;12.180000;M   ;1;;S80795XL;0
1008891;20.000000;Roll;30;;TSB876ZA;06;;ML-TTT299;Local Semi Gloss Label 51mm Round;20.000000;PC  ;1;;S80795XL;0
```

The 4th column contains in valid data, the correct data is stored in excel files on a shared drive. Importing the correct data into SQL is not an option because I am trying to integrate two systems without impacting on SQL. Each Excel file is named according to a product code which is a value in the SQL database as well (column number 6 in the csv file). The contents of each Excel file is below with each file containing different data depending on the product code:

```
1005    TMA208  CORE.CARDBOARD 25.4X33X1000MM (Black Stripes)   50  m   CORE_WI 10
2020    S80812XL    JUMBO Q812 NOIR-4,5-WAX3 1010MM X 18500M    23684.211   m   FILM_OUT    20
2025    TAD137ML    ADHESIVE SOLFREE 25MM X 330M    0.152   pc  AL1N1   20
2035    TAD123ML    ADHESIVE TRANSPARENT 25MM X 330M    0.303   pc  AL2N1   20
2040    TAD123ML    ADHESIVE TRANSPARENT 25MM X 330M    0.152   pc  AL3N1   20
2060    L15832ZA    TRANSPARENT LEADER ROLLS 300X250  18 MU/2   50  m   LEAD1   20
2065    L15834ZA    LEADER.METALLIZED.300MM 50  m   TRAIL1  20
2070    L17440ZA    BRIDGE.TRANSPARENT.48MM 50  m   BRIDGE  20
3026    TTT269  LABEL ADHESIVE.WHITE ROUND DIAM.53  1000    pc  LAB_ROLL    30
3027    ETI742  LABEL ADHESIVE UNIVERSAL 110X100MM (1F) 40  pc  LAB_BOX1    30
3040    TSE306  BOX USA 286X237X160MM   40  pc  BOX_1   30
3060    TFL104  FILM RETRACTABLE 310MMX1550M    129.029 m       30
3065    FSB001  STRAPPING BAND 9MM X 4000M (VIRGIN QUALITY, YELLOW) 35.76   m       30
3070    OPPBRN-48X900   OPP BROWN TAPE 48MMX900Y    16.24   m   ADH_PACK    30
```

What I want to achieve is read the System.Data.Datatable (column 6) to find the product code and store this as a variable, then search for the Excel file of the same name, read the contents of the excel file and match column 9 in the stored data table with column 2 in the excel file. Once I have that return column 7 in the excel file and update column 4 in the data table with this value. I need to do this with each row in the data table before eventually writing the CSV file.

I found the below code that I thought I could manipulate according to my needs and integrate it into my ps script, but I am not sure if this is the right way, or if there is a quicker way to do this?

```
#Declare the file path and sheet name
$file = "C:\Users\kfeb\Documents\Textfile\ExcelFile.xlsx"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
#Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
#Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
#Declare the starting positions
$rowName,$colName = 1,1
$rowAge,$colAge = 1,2
$rowCity,$colCity = 1,3
#loop to get values and store it
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
$name = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowName+$i,$colName).text
$age = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowAge+$i,$colAge).text
$city = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowCity+$i,$colCity).text

Write-Host ("My Name is: "+$name)
Write-Host ("My Age is: "+$age)
Write-Host ("I live in: "+$city)
}
#close excel file
$objExcel.quit()
```

Can anyone make sense of this question and if so provide some direction?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacon Bits was totally on the right track, just missing a little bit with the multiple files. Also, if you are using a modern version of PowerShell importing tables into PowerShell is a lot easier. So, I would make a HashTable, and load Excel data into it as needed as nested HashTables.

```
$RawCSV = GC c:\temp\Xperdyte.csv

$Headers = 1..$RawCSV[0].Split(';').Count|%{"Column$_"}

$CSV = $RawCSV | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header $Headers

$Lookup = @{}
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
ForEach($File in ($CSV.Column6|Select -Unique)){
    #Create record in main HT for this Excel file with an empty HT for the value
    $Lookup.Add($File,@{})

    #Open the workbook and import the data
    $WB = $XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kfeb\Documents\Textfile\$File.xlsx")
    $WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows | ForEach{$Lookup[$File].($_.Cells.Item(2).Value2) = $_.Cells.Item(7).Value2}

    #Close the workbook
    $wb.Close($false) | Out-Null
}
#Close Excel
$XL.Quit()|Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($XL) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable XL

$Output = ForEach($Item in $CSV){
    #If the item code can be found in the lookup table update Column4
    If($Item.Column9 -in $Lookup[($Item.Column6)].Keys){$Item.Column4 = $Lookup[($Item.Column6)][($Item.Column9)]}
    ($Headers|%{$Item.$_}) -join ';'
}

$Output | Set-Content ("c:\1_PRODUCTION\ARMOR\Bom\DocProd_Africa_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.csv" -f (get-date))
```

Comment: You guys are absolute geniuses, thank you. One quick question... The value we're looking for in the Excel file once it is opened, sometimes has a prefix and suffix in the CSV file, but not in the Excel file. Is there a way to search for the string within that value and get a result whether or not the prefix and suffix are there? Example, the file may contain a value abcdef, in the original csv file it may be 123abcdef456. Possible to cater for that variance?

Comment: Another question, I need to update another value in the csv file from the same excel file. I have tried updating the script to cater for this but running into a brick wall... So if I wanted to pull column 5 from the Excel file and update column 8 in the CSV file, how could I achieve this?

Comment: That drastically changes the way this would need to work on both accounts, and would definitely slow things down. To account for prefix/suffix you would need to loop through keys on the hashtable and look for partial matches. Then if you need to update multiple columns you would need to change the nested hashtables from be string values to object values, and reference the object property for the column you need to reference.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to take column 6 (product code) from the CSV, match it up to column 9 (also product code) and do a lookup for column 7 from the Excel file and save it to column 4 in the CSV.

First, fetch all the data from the Excel sheet.  I'm assuming there are no header rows in your Excel file, and you'll need to specify the worksheet name and filename correctly.

```
#Declare the file path and sheet name
$file = "C:\Users\kfeb\Documents\Textfile\ExcelFile.xlsx"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
#Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
#Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

$colProductCodeExcel = 9
$colOtherColumnExcel = 7

$SheetData = @{}

for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; ++$row) {
    $SheetProductCode = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$colProductCodeExcel).text
    $SheetOtherColumn = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$colOtherColumnExcel).text
    $SheetData[$SheetProductCode] = $SheetOtherColumn
}

$objExcel.Quit()
```

Now `$SheetData` is a lookup table.  If you have duplicate Product Codes, `$SheetData` will have the last Other Column value in the worksheet.

Now, fetch your data from SQL:

```
$dataSource = "DESKTOP-9CRH1HF\SQLEXPRESS"
$user = "sa"
$pwd = "Not4U2c@Al!"
$database = "Xperdyte"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;"

$query = "SELECT * from dbo.v_SpecProd_Export"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)
$connection.Dispose()

$colProductCodeSql = 6
$colOtherColumnSql = 4

$table | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_[$colOtherColumnSql] = $SheetData[$_[$colProductCodeSql]]
    } |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"', "" } |
    Set-Content c:\temp\Xperdyte.csv
```

If the data type for `$colOtherColumnSql` doesn't match `$SheetData[$colProductCodeSql]`, you may get errors or type conversion issues.  Beware of leading or trailing spaces.

I have not tested any of the above code.  I would not be surprised if there were bugs.

Comment: They have multiple Excel sheets. CSV Column 6 = Excel file name. Then lookup CSV Column 9 in Excel Column 2, and set CSV Column 4 to equal Excel Column 7.